# Return Null Reference in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have the following method in my program:

```
Public Function AddHandlerTo(ByVal compName As String) As System.Object
    For Each item In componentList
        If item.Name.Equals(compName) Then
            AddHandlerTo = item
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

As expected, because of how my `Return` statement is nested I am getting a warning in my compiler:

> Function 'AddHandler' doesn't return a value on all code paths.  A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used.

Now the purpose of this method is to help me (as the method name says) add handlers to specific objects that aren't easily accessible.  Essentially, each `item` in the `componentList` is a different child of the same parent object.  Regardless, it doesn't really matter for my question here.

I am trying to figure out how to add a final `Return` statement to the end of the method so that I no longer get the error.  If there is no object in the loop that matches the criteria, I want it to return an exception that no object exists or something like that.  Though I don't know how exactly to accomplish this, and my ability to find help via Google is apparently horrendous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically always use a return statement like this:

```
Public Function AddHandlerTo(ByVal compName As String) As System.Object
  Dim result As Object = Nothing
  For Each item In componentList
    If item.Name.Equals(compName) Then
        result = item
    End If
  Next
  Return result
End Function
```

or

```
Public Function AddHandlerTo(ByVal compName As String) As System.Object
  For Each item In componentList
    If item.Name.Equals(compName) Then
        Return item
    End If
  Next
  Return Nothing
End Function
```

Where ever you are calling this function, you would check to see if it returned something or nothing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to `Return item` inside the loop and `Return Nothing` at the end of the function? Seeing as it doesn't really need to loop any more if an item has already been found.

Comment: @VisualVincent  It's just a personal preference.  This is mine.

Comment: I was seeing it more from a performance perspective, but sure! For smaller lists it doesn't really make a notable difference. :)